# ConstraintLayout - pack items horizontally without setting width to match_parent

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I would like to achieve that simple view
[image]

However, when setting constraints like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/upgradeTo"
        style="@style/NewText.H2.Primary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="UPGRADE TO"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/premium"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/premium"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/premium"
        style="@style/NewText.H2.Accent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_rect_separator"
        android:backgroundTint="#fff3f8"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="PREMIUM"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/upgradeTo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My views aren't packed, but expanded
[image]

Usually, I use in that case `android:layout_width=match_parent` However, in that case I can't because my colorful background on PREMIUM will stretch too.

Is there another way to pack them without using `match_parent`?
Or the only way is to refactor my view (PREMIUM's background as separate `ImageView`).

Comment: what about by giving the width as 0dp

Comment: width `0dp` is the same as `match_parent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to add following line to your TextViews:

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle=”packed”
```

For details please visit this link:
https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb